TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable by using to_tf_dataset()
I'm trying to train my Transformer with my own tokenizer by using the following code :
def tokenization(examples):
    tokenized_examples = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        examples["text"],
        add_special_tokens=True,
        return_attention_mask=True,
        padding=True,
        truncation=True,
        pad_to_max_length=True,
        max_length=MAX_LENGTH,
        return_tensors='tf',
        return_token_type_ids=True
        
    )

tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(
    tokenization, remove_columns=["text"], 
)

collater = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")

train = tokenized_dataset['train'].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["input_ids", "token_type_ids", "attention_mask"],
    label_cols=["labels"],
    batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=collater
)

However this give me as an output the following error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Anyone can help me? Thank you

Hi, the error shows that you try to access a property or method of a variable that is None. In your case, it seems like the encode_plus method of the tokenizer object is returning None, which means there might be an issue with your tokenizer.First you need to Check if tokenizer is properly initialized,Check the tokenizer configuration
